# Transfer a python based application from google app engine to shared hosting

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, hosting

So basically I have a shell web application that uses python, it currently runs on google app engine, I want to transfer it to my shared web hosting. is it possible? there is already a python interpreter on it. what do I need to change in the settings in order for it to run as smoothly as in the google app engine?

Comment: It may be not possible, as Google App Engine uses its own web-framework and database. Can you give us more details? Are you using Django or the built-in framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is, "It depends."

Your application is at its core a WSGI app. So assuming that you aren't leveraging any custom Google App Engine APIs you should be able to spin your application up on another host utilizing a Python WSGI server like Gunicorn.

However, I'm assuming that your application does more than just render a static web page. In that case you're either going to have to rewrite portions of your application so that they don't rely on the custom App Engine stuff or use a framework like [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/) in order to ease the transition.